# Using custom sub domain on Tumblr - how does this work with Tumblr domains?

Tags: subdomain, tumblr

I've got a tumblr site running on a custom subdomain, for example: `one.mydomain.com` I set this up around 8 years ago.

I want to change it it to a new subdomain of the same domain, for example: `two.mydomain.com`

But when I've logged into Tumblr to do this, it keeps pointing me to Tumblr domains to register a new custom domain.

As I already own the main root domain which I host a non-Tumblr site on, so I only want to subdomain to point to Tumblr.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like Tumblr allows custom domains unless you had one previously. And if you turn off a "[Legacy Domain](https://help.tumblr.com/hc/en-us/articles/231256548-Legacy-Domains)" you can't reconnect it.

Also, according to the above page, SSL doesn't work with custom domains.

I have this setup and the old way used to be adding a CNAME or A Record with your new subdomain and the value domains.tumblr.com, but I am not sure if that will work now. It's no longer serving my tumblr. That's pretty disappointing.
[image: Tumblr DNS settings]

It all seems a bit dubious, they just want to sell domains would be my guess.

EDIT: Trying to get my blog address fixed and tried to click the support link for Legacy Domains and it is broken, not a good sign.

EDIT: My tumblr domain is working, but I assume it will stop working at some point in the future. You can try the CNAME record and see if that works, but I kind of doubt it unless Tumblr has your site set to serve on the subdomain also.